# Как в PascalABC сделать более-менее сложную математическую операцию?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Не понимаю как в PascalABC сделать более менее сложную математическую операцию, необходимо нечто подобное: x(x-a)(x-b)(x-c), можно конечно все сделать поэтапно, но я хочу сделать самый прямолинейный и простой способ решения этого выражения.

Comment: а в чём проблема?.. ))

Comment: в том, что я не понимаю как это в паскале написать что бы все выполнилось)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем проблема?

```
var 
  x, a, b, c: integer;

begin
  writeln('x, a, b, c'); readln(x, a, b, c);
  writeln(x*(x-a)*(x-b)*(x-c));
end.
```